# How to repair mongodb collection when index is corrupt?

Tags: mongodb, linux, ubuntu, mongo-repair

Mongo version: 2.6 I think one or more of my MongoDB index is corrupt which is not letting me delete the corrupt collection or make a backup with mongodump

Below is the error i get when i try to execute drop

```
>db.notifications.drop()
    "$err" : "no NamespaceDetails for index: { name: \"_id_\", ns: \"Bnk.notifications\", key: { _id: 1 }, v: 0 }",
            "code" : 17329
```

What can be done to get this collection removed or repaired if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to repair it by using `repairDatabase`.

More information:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/

Comment: it failed with same error